# Windows 2012 R2 - L1 cache N/A

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, xenserver

I have a number of Windows 2012 R2 servers running as VMs on a XenServer 7.0 host. When I open Task Manager in any VM, it reports the L1 cache to be "N/A". The server is a decent spec, only a year old, a Dell R730. Should I be concerned or is this normal, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

It's because XenServer doesn't pass this information to the VM's. Nothing to worry about.